# using grepl to fill a value in a variable produces strange results in R

Tags: r, string, replace, factors, grepl

I have a data.frame with a factor variable of 3 levels in R

```
'data.frame':   23848 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ Factor_var        : Factor w/ 3 levels "AAA","BBB",..: 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 ...
```

I want to overwrite one of the values with a different string using **grepl** function, but only if it is one of the values - otherwise it should remain the same

```
DF$Factor_var <- ifelse(grepl("AAA", DF$Factor_var), "ZZZ", DF$Factor_var)
```

After having run this transformation I get back **chr** variable with only string values that I just inpute, and values referring to the level value of the old strings

```
'data.frame':   23848 obs. of  14 variables:
  $ Factor_var       : chr  "ZZZ" "ZZZ" "3" "3" ...
```

whereas I am still expecting a factor variable with levels "ZZZ", "BBB" ... etc

Why is that? I just can't get around this problem!

THX

Comment: If it is a `factor` then change the `levels` i.e. `levels(DF$Factor_var) <- ifelse(grepl("AAA", levels(DF$Factor_var)), "ZZZ", levels(DF$Factor_var))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace function for the same

```
xy <-levels(df$Factor_var)

xy <- replace(xy,xy%in%"AAA","ZZZ")

levels(df$Factor_var) <- xy
```

Answer (score 0):

As the data is already a factor you can just change the level with `levels()<-`
No need for `grepl()` or `ifelse()` at this point.
So just do:

```
levels(DF$Factor_var) <- c("ZZZ","BBB","CCC")
```

For example:

```
var1 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "AA", "BB", "CC")
 df <- data.frame(var1)

> df$var1
[1] AA BB CC AA BB CC
Levels: AA BB CC
```

and then just do:

```
levels(df$var1) <- c("ZZ","BB","CC")
```

which results in:

```
df$var1
[1] ZZ BB CC ZZ BB CC
Levels: ZZ BB CC

str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
$ var1: Factor w/ 3 levels "ZZ","BB","CC": 1 2 3 1 2 3
```